# Can we get rid of the these tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

Note: I don't see a way to "flag" a tag other than posting in meta

1) "Non-Western"

This one:
https://music.stackexchange.com/tags/non-western/info

It (currently) only has one question, which is really about microtonal music in general, and does not directly touch on the  contrasts between Western/non-Western music.

In the long run, I believe that a set of tags that are more specific and informative in referring to particular musical styles is more useful than a binary "Western"/"Non-Western" setup.

Note, we already have "oriental", and "African", terms which seem comparable to "Western", which I interpret as, essentially, European based.

2) PRS and Epiphone

-These refer to specific brands of guitars.
- We don't currently have other guitar brand specific tags
- Both of these tags are only applied to the same, closed, question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

I saw these earlier today and came to the same conclusion. They've been removed from their questions, and any tag with no associated questions gets deleted automatically overnight.

Comment: On auto-deletion: so long as they don't have tag wikis (which this one apparently didn't, as it's gone now).